# XEN Server NFS SR read only

Tags: nfs, xen, read-only

We have two Boxes running XEN XCP. One SR is located on an FreeNAS 9 NFS share.

For some reason the NFS share turned read only which is pretty bad for one VM whose VDIs are located on the NFS SR.

I have found many hints to change the NFS mount options from soft to hard.

I just did not find a way to remount the share read-write without rebooting the host.

I tried mount -o remount,rw /path/to/my/SR to no avail. No error message, the share is still read-only.

How can I remount my SR read-write without rebooting my host(s) ?

Comment: "did not work" is clearly not enough information, you should give out an error message at least...

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason the server deided to export the share read-only. So re-exporting it read-write solved the issue.